# Limpiar una variable (cant) dentro de un método DataReceivedHandler

Tags: c#

¿Cómo puedo eliminar la información que tiene una variable encontrada en otra instancia o metodo?
No puedo hacer que esta variable (cant) se ponga en cero.
Ejemplo:

```
public class Program
{
        private int cant; // declare la variable

        static void Main(string[]args)// punto de entrada de una aplicación
        {
            Program Borrar = new Program {};//llamo la variable de la clase Program
             Borrar.cant = 5; //asigno un número a la variable cant
// Detecta cualquier dato recibido.
            Puerto_serie.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        {

        private static void DataReceivedHandler( object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) // Representa el método que manejará el evento DataReceived de un objeto SerialPort.
            {
            Program Borrar = new Program {};//)//llamo la variable de la clase Program
            Borrar.cant = 0; //asigno un número a la variable cant 0
            }
}
```

Comment: no entiendo que tratas de hacer... cada vez que haces Program Borrar = new... estas instanciando una nueva version de tu objeto... no es la misma de antes... cual es tu idea? te alcanzaba con hacer cant = lo que quieras, en cualquier lado...

Comment: El problema es que en la public class Program {} se encuentra la variable y luego empieza private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e){} donde quiero barrar dicha variable, la falla es : The name 'cant' does not exist in the current context. Por eso lo que hago es instanciar

Comment: Ahi entendi tu problema. Pero cuando instancias una nueva instancia del objeto, es una nueva variable. O usas static, o le pasas la variable al evento.

Comment: Use  static y es functional gracias, pero no logro entender porque lo use, me podrías explicar.

Comment: Leiste la dovumentacion sobre el scope de variables? Al decirle que es static, pertenece la misma a todas las instacias de la clase... pero ojo que si tu codigo es multihilos puede traer problemas

Comment: Y porque desde el evento no llamas directamente a cant que es privada de la clase program?